# Pass variable in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a function that is working perfectly:

```
function listimages($session) {
  $db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $query->select($db->quoteName(array('url_name', 'file_name')));
  $query->from($db->quoteName('#__webfoot_photo_studio_photos')); 
  $db->setQuery($query);
  $results = $db->loadObjectList();

return $results;              
}
```

Until I try to add the WHERE statement:

```
$query->where($db->quoteName('session' == '$session'));
```

'session' is the column in the database and $session is a value passed in through the function.

I get this error:

```
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3 SQL=SELECT `url_name`,`file_name` FROM `p9e2i_webfoot_photo_studio_photos` WHERE
```

Any suggestions or advice on fixing this syntax is truly appreciated.  I've been unable to find the solution.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Joomla but shouldn't it be `$query->where($db->quoteName('session' == $session));` ?

Comment: Thanks, but the suggestion syntax is the same as the one I'm trying to use.  It seems to throw an SQL error for some reason.

Comment: If you `var_dump($session);`, do you get any results?

Comment: No it's not, I removed the single quotes around $session. Apart from that, what's in $session and what's the query before you bind it to $db? (--> var_dump($query))

Comment: Equal is  `=` (single) not `==` (double) in SQL

Comment: Ah yes, so I pulled the double == and I also removed the variable for right now, I still get syntax issues on this:

$query->where($db->quoteName('session = 1'));

and this:

$query->where($db->quoteName('session' = 1));

the session is numbered 1,2,3,etc in the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
function listimages($session) {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($db->quoteName(array('url_name', 'file_name')))
          ->from($db->quoteName('#__webfoot_photo_studio_photos'))
          ->where($db->quoteName('session') . ' = ' . $db->quote($session));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();
    return $results;              
}
```

1. Removed the double `==` and used a single
2. Moved the `=` inside the quotes
3. Escaped the `$session` variable using `$db->quote($session)`
4. Your `quoteName` was incorrect so changed it around

Just remember that `quote` is used to escape values and `quoteName` is used for columns.

Whenever in doubt, always refer back to the Joomla Documentation for database queries as it provides some good examples:

http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much!  That's perfect -- I'll review the docs, I'm still very much learning the Joomla MVC.  Thanks again,

Comment: @BradM - You're more than welcome. Glad it helped :)